# Django not displaying images

Tags: python, django

Django not displaying image upload from admin, more then one day i try to fix it but no result can anyone help me.

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'D:/django_projects/BASE_DIR/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
...
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

models.py

```
...
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media/', default = 'media/no-img.jpg')
```

index.html

```
...
<li> <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ news.image }}" width=200 height =100 align="left" class="leftimg"/>
```

Comment: First, add an '/' at the end of MEDIA_ROOT

If it is not enough: use chrome's console (ctrl+shift+i) to see what files it tries to get. You will probably get an hint.

Comment: in urls.py try `from django.conf.urls.static import static` and `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: added / not work i try to get media/no-img.jpg (Mozilla Firebug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this: `{{ news.image.url }}`